# Crontab not running properly on MacOS

Tags: macos, cron, macos-mojave

I have set a crontab for a PHP script, which executes itself with no issues. My question is about the crontab; currently, I have this:

```
30,* 11 * * * php /Users/username/script.php >>/Users/username/script.log  2>/Users/username/script-error.log
```

With this crontab, I would expect the execution of the script every minute within 11:30 and 11:59. 
Instead, the script is being executed every minute within 11:00 and 11:59.

How can I set a crontab that allows me to run the script every minute within 11:30 an 11:59?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma in `30,*` acts as a separator for two values: the first value `30` and the second value `*`. As the second value (`*`) matches every minute, the script is executed every minute.

What you want is a range, which you could specify with `30-59`:

```
30-59 11 * * * php /Users/username/script.php >>/Users/username/script.log  2>/Users/username/script-error.log
```